# Traits vs template

Tags: scala

I m new in scala and i wonder what's the differences between traits and template ?
When should i use template and when should i use traits ?
thanks

Comment: Scala doesn't have "templates". What do you mean by it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends what you mean by template.
If it is ([wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_%28programming%29)) the feature that allow functions and classes to operate with [generic types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_programming), then template and trait are two orthogonal notions.

Traits can use generic type too (see this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252915/scala-how-to-define-generic-function-parameters) for instance), but there are here to offer an alternative to multiple inheritance, by offering [mixin class composition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005681/difference-between-abstract-class-and-trait/2006233#2006233) with stackable behavior.

Comment: by template i mean generics in c++ style or like in java

Comment: @lapinferoce: I thought so, and my answer stands. template ("generic") and traits (mixin class composition) are two different topics.

Answer (score 1):

"By template I mean generics as in C++ or Java" — lapinferoce

In that case, the contrast does not exist. Traits and classes (abstract or concrete) may both be generic. Only objects support neither parametric nor subtype polymorphism.