# Scala Abstract Class

Tags: scala

I'm new to scala and I'm not sure how to call the abstract class to create the desired object. any help would be great

```
abstract class Expr{
    case class Number(n:Double) extends Expr
    case class Sum(e1:Expr, e2: Expr) extends Expr
    case class Subtract(e1: Expr, e2: Expr) extends Expr
    case class Divide(e1: Expr, e2: Expr) extends Expr
    case class Abs(e1: Expr) extends Expr
    case class Mod(e1: Expr, e2: Expr) extends Expr
    def eval(e:Expr): Double = e match{
        case Number(n) => n;
        case Sum(e1,e2) => eval(e1) + eval(e2);
    }
}
object main{
    def main(args: Array[String])  {
        val e = Expr();
        println("hello");
    }
}
```

so i want to be able to create Expr object and use eval on it.
Thanks.

Comment: It looks like homework. What is your question exactly?

Answer (score 8):

You can instantiate Expr by adding `{}` to indicate an empty classbody. So your code would work if you wrote

```
val e = Expr() {};
val n = e.Number(1.0);
val sum = e.Sum(n, n);
println(e.eval(sum));
```

But I don't see why the case classes has to reside inside the Expr class. Why not write something like:

```
abstract class Expr {}

object Eval {
  def apply(e : Expr) = e match{
    case Number(n) => n;
    case Sum(e1,e2) => Eval(e1) + Eval(e2);
  }
}

case class Sum(e1 : Expr, e2 : Expr) extends Expr
```

Then you can reference them much nicer:

```
Eval(Sum(Number(1), Number(1)))
```

Answer (score 4):

What about that:

```
abstract class Expr {
  def eval: Double
}
case class Number(n:Double) extends Expr {
  def eval = n
}
case class Sum(e1:Expr, e2: Expr) extends Expr {
  def eval = e1.eval + e2.eval
}
case class Subtract(e1: Expr, e2: Expr) extends Expr {
  def eval = e1.eval - e2.eval
}

object Eval {
  def apply(e : Expr) = e.eval
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[update]

BTW I prefer @JensEgholm Eval object (with apply method) to my recommendation of adding eval to main below.  My point is that your eval code should be part of a Scala object for easy access and not part of any Scala abstract class.

[original]

That looks like sample/template code from Odersky's Programming in Scala (which I highly recommend by the way)

If so, you copied the template incorrectly.  There is no brace after `abstract class Expr`   That one line is a complete abstract class declaration.  Also the eval method should go in your main object.  Try this:

```
abstract class Expr
case class Number(n:Double) extends Expr
case class Sum(e1:Expr, e2: Expr) extends Expr
case class Subtract(e1: Expr, e2: Expr) extends Expr
case class Divide(e1: Expr, e2: Expr) extends Expr
case class Abs(e1: Expr) extends Expr
case class Mod(e1: Expr, e2: Expr) extends Expr

object main{
  def eval(e:Expr): Double = e match{
      case Number(n) => n;
      case Sum(e1,e2) => eval(e1) + eval(e2);
  }
    def main(args: Array[String])  {
      val n = Number(1.0);
      val m = Number(2.0);
        println(eval(Sum(n,m)));
    }
}
```

The program should print "3.0".

Answer (score 1):

As per Odersky, if you're new to scala you should be using traits in most cases unless you know why to use an abstract class in partucular.

[What is the advantage of using abstract classes instead of traits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1991042/scala-traits-vs-abstract-classes)

Examples above will be legal with traits and can then be 'mixed in' together.

```
scala> trait Expr
defined trait Expr

scala> case class Number(n:Double) extends Expr
defined class Number
```