# Abstract classes with constructor parameters in Scala

Tags: scala

I have the following class model:

```
sealed abstract class Tile(val coordinate: Int, val isOccupied: Boolean) {
  def isEmpty() : Boolean
  def getPiece() : Option[Piece]
}

case class EmptyTile(coordinate: Int) extends Tile(coordinate, false) {
  override def toString: String = "" +coordinate
  override def isEmpty() = true
  override def getPiece() = None
}

case class OccupiedTile(coordinate: Int, val piece: Piece) extends Tile(coordinate, true) {
  override def toString = piece.toString
  override def isEmpty = false
  override def getPiece = Some(piece)
}
```

and I get the following error:

```
Error:(6, 22) overriding value coordinate in class Tile of type Int;
 value coordinate needs `override' modifier
case class EmptyTile(coordinate: Int) extends Tile(coordinate, false) {
                 ^
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Request to see Piece class, adding here:

```
import Alliance.Alliance
import PieceType.PieceType

abstract class Piece(val piecePosition: Int, val pieceType : PieceType, val alliance: Alliance) extends Movable {
}

object PieceType extends Enumeration {
  type PieceType = Value
  val PAWN, KNIGHT, BISHOP, ROOK, QUEEN, KING = Value
}
```

Comment: What is your version of Scala?

Comment: Could you share your Tile and Piece classes ? It would be helpful to REPL it out :)

Comment: Tile is included already, I'll add Piece

Comment: @vptheron I am using 2.10 I believe

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your abstract class `Tile` declares a `val coordinate`, making this value publicly accessible. Your case class `EmptyTile` implicitly declares `coordinate` as a val as well (case class "magic"). Basically, your case class is effectively trying to override a value already provided by your abstract class.

You can either remove the `val` in your abstract class declaration, or not make `EmptyTile` and `OccupiedTile` case classes.

Edit: proposed alternative after comment:

```
trait Tile {
  def coordinate: Int
  def isOccupied: Boolean
  def isEmpty() : Boolean = !isOccupied
  def getPiece() : Option[Piece]
}

case class EmptyTile(coordinate: Int) extends Tile {
  override def toString: String = "" +coordinate
  val isOccupied = false
  def getPiece() = None
}

case class OccupiedTile(coordinate: Int, val piece: Piece) extends Tile {
  override def toString = piece.toString
  val isOccupied = true
  def getPiece = Some(piece)
}
```

Comment: If I remove the val in my abstract class - will it be a var?  Or will it simply not exist in the base class?  I suppose I can get rid of the case classing, but this really sucks...

Comment: @AmirAfghani No, it won't be a `var`, it just won't be used since the constructor isn't actually doing anything with it. If you want it accessible in `Tile`, I'd recommend removing it from the constructor and declaring `def coordinate: Int` (abstract) within it. Then you can keep your case classes.

Comment: By passing in coordinate as an Int, are you implicitly overriding the def declaration in the trait?

Comment: `coordinate` is undefined in the trait. Since it is a constructor argument of the case classes, you automatically implement it - not override, since the trait does not give any value to the member. The fact that it is an Int does not change anything.

Answer (score 1):

`case class` automatically makes its arguments `val`s. This is why the argument `coordinate` to `EmptyTile`, understood as `val coordinate`, conflicts with the abstract class's `val coordinate`.

One way to fix this is to have `coordinate` and `isOccupied` be defined as abstract in `Tile`. `Tile` can even be a trait instead of an abstract class:

```scala
sealed trait Tile {
  def coordinate: Int
  def isOccupied: Boolean
  ...
}

case class EmptyTile(coordinate: Int) extends Tile {
  def isOccupied = false
  ...
}

case class OccupiedTile(coordinate: Int, piece: Piece) extends Tile {
  def isOccupied = true
  ...
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer.  Doesn't it seem wrong though to have Tile be a trait vs a 'noun' like thing?  It seems like abstract classes with case class overrides are just not developer friendly in Scala.  +1 for the answer

Comment: Another way to look at it is that in your case, the functionality you need from `Tile` could be completely specified as a trait (common interface), so why use a class when a trait would work just as well? See http://stackoverflow.com/q/1991042/

Comment: In terms of "noun" vs. "trait", you can read `EmptyTile extends Tile` as "`EmptyTile` is a `Tile`, and a `Tile` is something that has these properties"... I'm not sure what's not-noun-like about that.

Comment: I suppose you're right.  I was viewing traits as interfaces - which perhaps is wrong

Comment: I think it's correct to view them as interfaces, which is exactly why they work well for your `Tile`.