# Covariance/SubType in ListBuffer[BaseType]

Tags: java, scala

I have three classes that all implement analogues functionality but differ in subtle details.  I wanted to create an abstract base class and move the code that is shared up.  Now I'm stuck.

Each subclass has a `ListBuffer` that holds objects of another relation, that is a sublclass of some basic type.  More concretely:

```
trait data {
  def parseXML();
}

trait ConcreteDataA extends Data {
  override def parseXML(): Unit = {...}
}

abstract class Worker {
   protected var data: ListBuffer[Data] = _

   def loadXML(): Unit = {
     val path: String = getPath()
     ... // Parse XML-file at path and put data into data-ListBuffer 
   }

   def getPath(): String;
}

object ConcreteWorkerA extends Worker {
  data = new ListBuffer[ConcreteDataA] // Here the expected type differs

  override def getPath(): String = {
    return "pathTo/ConcreteWorkerA/s/WorkingPlace"
  }
}
```

I'm unsure how to best solve this problem and grateful for any input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a wildcard type for the generic parameter:  `ListBuffer[_ <: Data]`.  You could also make the whole class/trait generic with parameter `T <: Data`, and then declare the variable as `ListBuffer[T]`.

You should also consider why you are using an abstract class here at all.  You can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1991042/what-is-the-advantage-of-using-abstract-classes-instead-of-traits) about the (very few) advantages of an abstract class over a trait.  You might also reconsider why `data` is declared as a `var`, and why it is instantiated in `Worker`.  You might reconstruct your types like this:

```
trait Worker[T <: Data]
{
   protected val data: ListBuffer[T] //Not var, and uninstantiated
   def loadXML: Unit = ???
   def getPath: String
}

object ConcreteWorkerA extends Worker[ConcreteDataA]
{
  override val data = new ListBuffer[ConcreteDataA] // Here the expected type differs
  override def getPath: String = "foo"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

My first guess would be an abstract type member:

```
abstract class Worker {
  type DataType <: Data

  protected var data: ListBuffer[DataType] = _
}

object ConcreteWorkerA extends Worker {
  type DataType = ConcreteDataA

  data = new ListBuffer[ConcreteDataA]
}
```

But then, why is `data` even declared in `Worker`? Its lack of initialization with `_` is also a code smell. You could at least declare it as an abstract val:

```
abstract class Worker {
  type DataType <: Data

  protected val data: ListBuffer[DataType]
}

object ConcreteWorkerA extends Worker {
  type DataType = ConcreteDataA

  protected val data = new ListBuffer[ConcreteDataA]
}
```