# Trait vs Abstract Class in Scala

Tags: scala

Assuming no multiple inheritance and no concerns about interoperability with Java, are the two following declarations equal?

```
sealed trait Foo { def x: Int }
case object Bar extends Foo { val x = 5 }
```

and

```
sealed abstract class Foo(val x: Int)
case object Bar extends Foo(5)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the advantage of using abstract classes instead of traits?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1991042/what-is-the-advantage-of-using-abstract-classes-instead-of-traits)

Comment: I've read that thread, I'm asking about this specific example from a purely behavioral point of view.

Comment: I am not a Scala expert, but I would assume they need to be equivalent in the same way that it would be equivalent comparing (for this concrete example) an abstract class and an interface in Java.

Comment: note that you need `val x: Int` in abstract class example, otherways it's just unused constructor parameter which results in ` error: value x is not a member of object Bar` when calling `Bar.x`

Comment: @Łukasz I see! Thanks for pointing this out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, some modifications to your code (see below). I dropped the `case` as it is not relevant here. I also added `val` in the constructor of `Foo2` as `x` is otherwise not accessible in `Bar2`.

```
sealed trait Foo { def x: Int }
object Bar extends Foo { val x = 5 }

sealed abstract class Foo2(val x: Int)
object Bar2 extends Foo2(5)

object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]) : Unit = {
    println( Bar.x )
    println( Bar2.x )
  }
}
```

> Are the two following declarations equal?

We need to define, what **equal** means:

- Equal wrt. general structure: **No**. A trait is not an abstract class. A trait can have no constructor parameters, while a class can. On the other hand, a class or object (here `Bar2`) can only derive from *one* (abstract) class, while it could mix-in multiple traits. A good comprehesion on traits vs. abstract class is given here: http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/traits.html#12.7 if you need to decide on a trait or a class.
- Equal wrt. byte code: **No**. Just run `javap -v <classfile>` to convince yourself
- Equal wrt. `Bar` and `Bar2` only: **Yes**. Both can be accessed and used identically. Both are singletons and they expose a member variable `x` that is readable (but not writable) from outside.

Also the output of `scalac -print` is quite helpful, to see what is going on:

```
sealed abstract trait Foo extends Object {
  def x(): Int
};
object Bar extends Object with com.Foo {
  private[this] val x: Int = _;
  <stable> <accessor> def x(): Int = Bar.this.x;
  def <init>(): com.Bar.type = {
    Bar.super.<init>();
    Bar.this.x = 5;
    ()
  }
};
sealed abstract class Foo2 extends Object {
  <paramaccessor> private[this] val x: Int = _;
  <stable> <accessor> <paramaccessor> def x(): Int = Foo2.this.x;
  def <init>(x: Int): com.Foo2 = {
    Foo2.this.x = x;
    Foo2.super.<init>();
    ()
  }
};
object Bar2 extends com.Foo2 {
  def <init>(): com.Bar2.type = {
    Bar2.super.<init>(5);
    ()
  }
};
object Main extends Object {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    scala.this.Predef.println(scala.Int.box(Bar.x()));
    scala.this.Predef.println(scala.Int.box(Bar2.x()))
  };
  def <init>(): com.Main.type = {
    Main.super.<init>();
    ()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, these are not equivalent and can lead to trouble later with initialization order. I've added exactly the same line of code to each, showing they were never equal code blocks.

```
sealed trait Foo {
    def x: Int
    val calc = x * 5 / 2  //at the time this runs, x is actually 0
  }
  case object Bar extends Foo {
    val x = 5

  }


  sealed abstract class Foo2(x: Int){
    val calc = x * 5 / 2
  }
  case object Bar2 extends Foo2(5)

  println(Bar.calc)
  println(Bar2.calc)

  //output  0  12
```

Comment: Downvote, as answer is not comprehensive enough.  Second, initialization order needs extreme care, but is not relevant in the case, user2066880 has given.