# Scala - extends vs with

Tags: scala, extends

I am confused. In my existing project, I am not able to find the difference between `extends` and `with`. Could you please help me?

Comment: extends is for the object or class while with is for the interface or trait

Comment: Martin Odersky wrote a nice answer for this http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/10145.html

Answer (score 44):

If you have multiple `class`es or `trait`s to inherit, the first one is always `extends`, and the following >=0 `class`/`trait` to be `with`s.

But remember that you can only *inherit* <=1 (abstract) class, which means if you need to inherit a parent class (`Parent`), it should always comes at first of the form `... extends Parent ...`, and no more classes can be inherited to the derived class.

```
trait T1
trait T2
class P1
class P2

class C1 extends T1
class C2 extends T1 with T2
class C3 extends T2 with T1
class C4 extends P1 with T1
/// class C5 extends T1 with P1 // invalid
/// class C6 extends P1 with P2 // invalid
```

`with` is in fact bound to the class/trait that is `extend`ed, e.g., `class C7 extends P1 with T1 with T2` reads `class C7 extends (P1 with T1 with T2)`.

Note that this is only from the viewpoint of ***syntax***, the ***semantic*** differences can be referred from the followings:

1. use of `trait` and (`abstract`) `class` is
   [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1991042/what-is-the-advantage-of-using-abstract-classes-instead-of-traits);
2. The resolution rule is the so-called
   [class linearization](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/05-classes-and-objects.html#class-linearization); there is [a post about it](http://jim-mcbeath.blogspot.sg/2009/08/scala-class-linearization.html#rules).

Answer (score 26):

In Scala, you can inherit from `class`es (concrete or `abstract`) and `trait`s. In a similar way to how you can extend only one class, but implement as many interfaces as you'd like in Java, you're only allowed to inherit from one `class`, but as many `trait`s as you'd like.

If you are extending a `class`, that class should immediately follow the `extends` keyword. Any `trait`s you are extending from should follow, separated by `with` keywords.

If you are not extending a class, you can put your first `trait` right after the `extends` keyword and continue after that.

Just as in Java, every class is a subclass of `Object` whether you explicitly declare it or not, every (user-defined) class in Scala `extends AnyRef with ScalaObject` whether or not you include that explicitly.

The following sets of declarations are therefore equivalent:

```
class MyClass { ... }
class MyClass extends AnyRef with ScalaObject { ... }

class MyClass extends MySuperClass { ... }
class MyClass extends MySuperClass with ScalaObject { ... }

class MyClass extends MyTrait1 with MyTrait2 { ... }
class MyClass extends AnyRef with MyTrait1 with MyTrait2 { ... }

class MyClass extends MySuperClass with MyTrait1 with MyTrait2 { ... }
```

The last example is not the same if you change the order of `MySuperClass`, `MyTrait1`, and `MyTrait2`. In particular, you cannot put a trait in front of a class and the order in which you stack traits is important if they both have implementations for the same methods. (In that case, the last one "wins".)

Remember also that only `class`es in Scala can have parameters, so you'll only ever be able to attach parameters to the type after the `extends` keyword, never to any of the types listed after `with`.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Is there a documentation about why the first trait has to be after "extends" keyword instead of a "with" keyword? In your example, it's class MyClass extends MyTrait1 with MyTrait2 { ... }

Comment: That's just the syntax. No special reason except to make the English sound reasonable. ("extends _ with _" is a reasonable descriptive phrase).

Answer (score 12):

The first thing you inherit from can either be a trait or a class, using the `extends` keyword.

```
trait SomeTrait
class SomeClass

class ThisIsValid extends SomeTrait
class ThisAsWell extends SomeClass
```

You can define further inherited traits (and only traits) using the `with` keyword.

```
class AlsoThisWorks extends SomeClass with SomeTrait
```

If a trait inherits from a class you cannot use it like in the above example.

That's it regarding the `extends` and `with` keywords. If you want to learn more about [classes](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/classes.html) and [traits](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/traits.html) the official documentation goes in depth on the topic.