# Abstract class and trait use case

Tags: scala

Hi Can anyone help me with the real time use case of abstract class and trait in scala specially with respect to spark . I know the functionality of both but I am not sure about real time use case as I do not have the practical exposure.

Comment: Here it is:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1991042/what-is-the-advantage-of-using-abstract-classes-instead-of-traits

Comment: It says with respect to Spark.

Comment: I know the concepts but I want practical implementation in real time world. It would be very helpful.

Comment: Real time or just in the real application?